# Course completion report is not working properly it showing the wrong output

Tags: moodle

i am trying to implement the course completion status block in my moodle  to check this i made a student account in that status is showing pending and also other status is not working correctly i give the course completion setting and activity completion setting. And if i click on "More Details" this page is opening (picture 2) in which it also showing incomplete and complete the quiz and pass also still it showing incomplete.

[image: picture 1]             [image: picture 2]

And after this i check in admin from course report so this also reflecting there, in (picture 3) self completion and course complete is unmarked.

[image: picture 3]

I need this to check the student is complete the task properly so i can provide the certificate to him "not custom certificate".

So Anyone could please suggest something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to check that your cron file is working or not for that go to administration>server>scheduled task in that check for the completion regular task  is working if not then first work for you cron then it will automatically work.
And your self completion is still not responding after that this is because you didn't add the self completion so add this block and manually complete the course and then it will properly.
For cron i suggest you only go for moodle docs only and then implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Check-in Site administration > Server > Scheduled tasks that the task 'Calculate regular completion data' is running frequently enough, such as every minute. You should also have a link "Run now" to run this task straight away. If that doesn't resolve the issue then there might be a problem with your cron.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).